# displaying rest of contents of an array

Tags: javascript, for-loop

I am trying to use a FOR loop to display contents of an array.

the function I want to create is similar to underscore.js _.rest function except the objective is touse a FOR loop.

rest(anyArray, n);

so if I were to enter "rest([1,2,3,4,5], 3);", I want to return "[4,5]".

Here is what I have and it does not work:

```
rest: function (anyArray, n) {
  var isArray = (anyArray instanceof Array),
    isNum = (typeof n === 'number'),
    result = new Array,
    valRange = (n >= 0);
  if (isArray && isNum) {
    for (len = anyArray.length, i = 0, j = (len - (n + len)); i < j, n < len; i++, j++) {
      result[i] = anyArray[j];
    }
    return result;
  }
}
```

Comment: The method already exists on `Array`. [It's called `slice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice). `[1,2,3,4,5].slice(3)` => `[4,5]`.

Answer (score 1):

```
rest: function (anyArray, n) {
    return anyArray.slice(n);
}
```

---

```
rest: function (anyArray, n) {
    var output = [];
    for (; n < anyArray.length; n++) {
        output.push(anyArray[n]);
    }
    return output;
}
```

Comment: is there a way I can use a for loop to do this?

Comment: @ShafiRazzack I guess .. but why?

Comment: @ExplosionPills—'cos that's what the homework question asked?

Answer (score 0):

The part that leads to "not working" is `j = (len - (n + len))`: Essentially, you say `j = n`, and then you are looping while `i < j`. I'd expect that what you actually want is `j < len`. Also, you should add the `var` keyword:

```
rest: function(anyArray, n){
    var isArray = (anyArray instanceof Array),
        isNum = (typeof n === 'number'),
        result = [];
    if (isArray && isNum) {
        for (var len = anyArray.length, i = 0, j = n; j < len; i++, j++) {
            result[i] = anyArray[j];
        }
        return result;
    }
    // else?
}
```

Of course, just using the native [`slice` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) would be much easier.